# How to auto-resize other view while doing translate animation?

Tags: android

I don't have any clue, also by Google, how to do translate animation on my view while the view below it also resized according to above view movement.

So, I have this code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mode"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this java code:

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mode);
mHideAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", view.getY() + 50, view.getY());
mShowAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", view.getY(), view.getY() + 50);
mHideAnimation.setDuration(1000);
mShowAnimation.setDuration(1000);
```

And later I call:

```
mShowAnimation.start();
```

or

```
mHideAnimation.start();
```

Is there anyone can advise me how to resize the Listview automatically while I am translating the Textview?

Comment: What is your goal exactly? You might want to do a ScaleAnimation on the "other" View.

Comment: @Rendy which view r u talking about?the top view is text view and which is the view below it?couldn't get you.

Comment: lol sorry for that.. I edited my question..

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I have tried using ScaleAnimation but the result is very not good.. Looking for another solution..